# Does ROS run on AGL?

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does ROS run on AGL?

[www.automotivelinux.org](http://www.automotivelinux.org)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282071/does-ros-run-on-agl?/) by [Richard Guan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33609/richard-guan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-02-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't seen anyone on this forum asking about AGL before. I had a quick look at the AGL mailing list and found a similar question, but no report of success or failure: https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/automotive-discussions/2017-June/004319.html

ROS can be compiled to run on most flavors of Linux, assuming you can meet the dependencies specified in [REP-003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html). I'd suggest you start with the robot metapackage, since it includes the command-line tools but doesn't include rviz (which can be difficult to build and run on embedded Linux)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-08**:
From a quick look it appears AGL is Yocto based, so perhaps [bmwcarit/meta-ros](https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros) can be of help (if it doesn't already answer the OP's question). @Lukas Bulwahn is maintaining that.